# Impossible to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a new computer

Tags: system-installation, kernel, 18.04, amd-processor, amdgpu

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a brand new computer but I can't get it done. I'm getting a lot of lines like :

```
AMD-VI: Completion-Wait loop timed out
```

or

```
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
```

I've recreated my Ubuntu USB key 4 or 5 times with different software and support without any luck.
I modified the iommu to disabled but no change.
I installed Windows 10 without trouble, and everything is working fine there.

- Motherboard: b350 PC MATE
- CPU: Ryzen 5 2600X
- GPU: radeon RX 570

Some screenshots of my issue:

- https://ibb.co/gDqxJU
- https://ibb.co/gpLmCp
- https://ibb.co/hwpeXp
- https://ibb.co/jyVEyU

iso md5 is ok, legacy support in bios is on.
I tried nomodetest, acpi=off and nolapic as suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).

Comment: Did you verify the download was valid?  (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu)

Comment: @karel This is a kernel panic according to the screenshots, I don’t think this case is included in the canonical question.

Comment: This is a problem with bugged firmware. Try to enable legacy support and boot your flash drive on UEFI. "I modified the iommu to disabled" Don't, if you do that you need to install a 32-bit system.

Comment: @guiverc I had no doubt about it but doesn't hurt to check. md5 is ok

Comment: @Rinzwind I will try that

Comment: disable secure boot?

Comment: @Rinzwind the issue is still the same

Comment: @karel I tried with acpi=off, nolapic and nomodetest (nomodetest only didn't change the result), I'm reaching the ubuntu loading screen but stay stuck there

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install and run Ubuntu by editing the commands before booting (<kbd>e</kbd> on the GRUB screen) and adding `iommu=soft` among `quiet splash`.

***edit***

Well, it partialy resolved my issue. I was able to install ubuntu, yes, but now I need to update the grub command each time I have a new kernel version. Plus my computer is not booting on grub, windows is. If I want to boot on linux, I need to enter my boot option and select my partition. I tried [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344688/how-to-point-to-grub-instead-of-windows-loader) but had a message on boot repair : `grub-efi-amd64-signed purge cancelled`

Comment: After you boot to Ubuntu (by selecting the partition) edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and add the same `iommu=soft` after `quiet splash`. Save the file, and open a terminal and enter the following command: `sudo update-grub`. Let me know if this helps.