# AMD-VI : ubuntu 18.04.2 not booting

Tags: boot, 18.04

Since yesterday, my computer won't boot on ubuntu. I did some system updates and tried to install a software (vscodium via .deb file), apt failed giving me a message about my cpu (don't remember exactly what) so I restarted my computer, or at least tried to restart it.
Windows 10 (dual boot) is working fine.
I downloaded ubuntu 19.04 to boot on liveusb but it won't boot either.
While trying to boot I encounter `AMD-VI: Completion-Wait loop timed out`
 message along with `iommu ivhd0 IOTLB_INV_TIMEOUT` or something.

I already had issues installing ubuntu and upgrade linux kernel but managed to workaround with iommu=soft stuff ([Impossible to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a new computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070387/impossible-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-on-a-new-computer)). I didn't have any issues for several months so I thought it was behind me.

Computer specs :

- Motherboard: b350 PC MATE
- CPU: Ryzen 5 2600X
- GPU: radeon RX 570
- Ubuntu 18.04.2

At this point I really don't know what to do...
I can't even launch recovery mode.

Bios is up-to-date

I managed to access my terminal, update-grub didn't help, but when I typed `sudo apt update` I had `E: Error reading the CPU table`. /usr/share/dpkg/cputable was missing, I copied a version of the file I found in /snap/core18/941/usr/share/dpkg/cputable and now I have `E: Cannot find dpkg tuplet or triplet table`

Comment: Have you tried with the IOMMU parameter again?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia yes, iommu=soft, iommu=off, no difference

Comment: @starkus no, I'm using the default splash screen, and I don't have onboard GPU

Comment: Did you update the motherboard Bios?  Since your board is 1st generation, and your CPU is 2nd generation Ryzen, therefore BIOS has to be updated.

Comment: Restart your system and press `shift` key to enter into GRUB menu. Use `Up/Dn` arrows to select `Ubuntu` and then press `e`. A screen will appear, and look for the line `linux`. Use `up/Dn` arrows and reach that line. Press `end` key to reach end of line containing `linux`. Enter a space character followed by 3. Press  Ctrl+X to boot. You will be taken to terminal TTY and there you enter your login username and password. Now you issue `sudo update-grub` . Finally type `reboot`. After rebooting reach GRUB menu pressing `shift` key and try to boot by selecting `ubuntu`. Please report. Thanks.

Comment: @Mitch the bios is uptodate, it's the first thing I've tried

Comment: @Marmayogi I did what you suggested, it didn't change a thing, but in the prompt, I tried `sudo apt update` and it told me : `E: Error reading the CPU table`. It appears that the file /usr/share/dpkg/cputable is missing

Comment: Please run the following: `sudo dpkg --configure -a` , `sudo apt-get update`, and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: @Marmayogi `sudo dpkg --configure -a` gives dpkg: unknown command

Comment: Please issue this command and find out `dpkg` binary is missing? `ls -l /usr/bin/dpkg`

Comment: it's in french but it says something like `ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/dpkg': no file or directory of this type`

Comment: We need to move to a chat session, @ThEBiShOp

Comment: ok, how do we proceed ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93337/discussion-between-marmayogi-and-thebishop).